# How to remove empty json object from nested json structure

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

In my current JSON, I am getting an empty JSON object **`{}`** inside **`dummy_var5`**. The empty object is inside an array which is inside an object itself.

```json
{
  "dummy_var1": "abc",
  "dummy_var2": [
    {
      "item": {
        "action": "test",
        "po": {
          "id": "abc"
        },
        "ot": "test1",
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "dummy_var3": {
    "dummy_var4": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "test2"
  },
  "dummy_var5": [
    {
      "ref": "test",
      "name": "test1",
      "type": null
    },
    {}
  ],
  "dummy_var6": [
    {
      "role": "test",
      "ref": "test1",
      "partyDescription": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Considering this structure does not change, Is there any way to remove this via jolt. We tried using third party tool 'atlasmap' but couldn't achieve the desired result.

Expected output :-

```json
{
  "dummy_var1": "abc",
  "dummy_var2": [
    {
      "item": {
        "action": "test",
        "po": {
          "id": "abc"
        },
        "ot": "test1",
        "id": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "dummy_var3": {
    "dummy_var4": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "test1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "test2"
  },
  "dummy_var5": [
    {
      "ref": "test",
      "name": "test1",
      "type": null
    }
  ],
  "dummy_var6": [
    {
      "role": "test",
      "ref": "test1",
      "partyDescription": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // the attributes other than "dummy_var5"
      "dummy_var5": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.[&1].&" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the match `"*":"&"` of the line  `"*": "&2.[&1].&"` returns the **null** value from the leaf node for this level, and so removes the innermost null object `{}`